# How can I implement library which will supports data types for variables in PHP 5.x.x ? Instead of loose datatype binding in PHP

Tags: java, php, c++

I want to extend core PHP library and want to build wrapper library which is supports strict data types in PHP, As like JAVA and C++.

Please give me the steps / any suggestions or any reference URLs. From where should I start. It will good if I can extends the code PHp library instead of modification in core distribution.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by looking at [SPL DataTypes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php)